# How would I condense this rails form into one button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for @asset do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :remove_picture %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove" %> 
<% end %>
```

How could I just make this one button that does `:remove_picture` and `submit`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the checkbox to a hidden field on the form...

If it were me, I'd look at something like [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) and handle this via AJAX on the controller.  This way the button would call a controller action, say `remove_picture` and return a JS response which could update your view.

Example:

`button_to([remove_picture, @asset], { method: :delete })`

- Note:  `method: :delete` may not be needed - depends on your routes.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with AJAX but I'm going to give that a shot. Could the action be called from a link_to rather than a button_to?

Comment: Sure.  Then you'd have something `link_to @asset, { method: :delete }`

Comment: Also note, you don't need to use AJAX in my answer.  I've updated my answer to give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the API dock for the form_for helper:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

You can force the form to use the full array of HTTP verbs by setting

```
:method => (:get|:post|:put|:delete)
```

So your code might look like

```
 <%= form_for(@asset, html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
     <%= f.submit "Remove" %> 
 <% end %>
```